# How do I get the HTTP error code of a failed jsonp request using jquery-jsonp, in the error callback function?

Tags: jquery, error-handling, jsonp

I'm using jaubourg's [jquery-jsonp module](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp) to fetch data from a different domain than my site is on. I'm using this module since jQuery's `ajax` function doesn't support error handling for JSONP requests.

When I make a request using the `jsonp` function of this library to a non-existing URL, the `error` callback function is called, but I can't see how I can retrieve the HTTP error code, to see what went wrong.

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/blob/master/doc/API.md), the only data available in the `error` callback function is the `xOptions` object that defines the request, and a `textStatus` string which is either "error" or "timeout". In my case it's "error", but I can't see how I can see *which* error has happened.

Comment: Are you sure [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) does not support that? >> "complete callback option fires, when the request finishes, whether in failure or success. It receives the jqXHR object, as well as a string containing the success or error code."

Answer (score 1):

You can't

Let's recall what JSONP does. Consider this:

```
$.jsonp({
  url: "http://service.org/path?param1=xx&param2=xx",
  callback: "myCbFn",
  error: myErFn
});
```

What this will do is add something like this to the DOM:

```
<script type="application/javascript"
        src="http://service.org/path?param1=xx&param2=xx&jsonp=myCbFn"
        onerror="myErFn">
</script>
```

Your error handling function will be called by the DOM event on the script tag.

It's very important to distinguish JSONP from AJAX (XML HTTP Request).